# How can I start X11 on a Linux system without graphics hardware?

Tags: linux, xorg, amazon-ec2, xulrunner, xul

I want to run some xulrunner based program on EC2 - it will run automatically but it needs some display as far as I understand. That probably requires X11 with some dummy screen driver.

How can I do that? (or run xulrunner on EC2 otherwise).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative solution: XVNC, which you can connect to with a VNC client if you want to see what is happening: http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~magi/doc/vnc/xvnc.html

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a common solution to this is to run [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), which is a X11 server with a virtual framebuffer. It doesn't actually display anything, but other than that it behaves exactly like any other X11 server.

Answer (score 2):

`Xvfb` is an X server that does not actually connect to any hardware.